# If parshuram killed kshatriyas 21 times how do many kshatriyas like rajputs exists today?

Tags: kshatriya

If parshuram killed  kshatriyas 21 times how do many kshatriyas like rajputs exists today,did the wifes of kshatriyas did niyogas with brahman rishis to give birth to new breed of Kshatiryas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leftover Kshatriyas after Lord Parashurama's sanitization](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12438/leftover-kshatriyas-after-lord-parashuramas-sanitization)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*did the wifes of kshatriyas did niyogas with brahman rishis to give birth to new breed of Kshatiryas?*

**Yes**

After the genocide of Kshatriyas by Parashuram, Kshetriya women used Brahmanas for enduring the Kshetriya race.

> The son of Jamadagni (Parasurama), after twenty-one times making the
> earth bereft of Kshatriyas wended to that best of mountains Mahendra
> and there began his ascetic penances. **And at that time when the earth
> was bereft of Kshatriyas, the Kshatriya ladies, desirous of offspring,
> used to come, O monarch, to the Brahmanas and Brahmanas of rigid vows
> had connection with them during the womanly season alone, but never, O
> king, lustfully and out of season. And Kshatriya ladies by thousands
> conceived from such connection with Brahmanas.** Then, O monarch, were
> born many Kshatriyas of greater energy, boys and girls, so that the
> Kshatriya race, might thrive. And thus sprang the Kshatriya race from
> Kshatriya ladies by Brahmanas of ascetic penances. And the new
> generation, blessed with long life, began to thrive in virtue. And
> thus were the four orders having Brahmanas at their head
> re-established.
>
> [[Section 64, Adivansavatarana Parva ,  Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01065.htm)

Thus, it is true that Brahmanas contributed Kshatriya women in-order to save the Kshetriya race. And as a result new generation of Kshetriya race came into existence.

*But I am not sure about whether the Kshetriyas [born at those times](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/36112/661) have any connection with modern Rajputs.*

Comment: Niyoga means  you can explain

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7625/which-hindu-text-generally-describes-the-rules-of-niyoga

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud OP may go through that link...

Comment: How come they become Kshatriyas then? If a gal gets married to Brahmin, she will also turn to Brahmin right just like in Muslims. And thus the baby belongs to Brahmin community and not Kshatriyas?

Comment: @Hansiemithun An anuloma marriage is a marriage where the husband is from a higher class than the wife. The offspring of such a marriage belong to the mother’s class. You can refer it  here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29599/661

Comment: @Hansiemithun Although it is not about marriage. I am focusing on off-springs.

Comment: @hanugm, interesting learning for me, thank you _/\_

Comment: I thick niyoga means surrogacy

Answer (score 1):

No... No no no..A big no

This is a big misconception that Parshuram deprived the entire  World of Kshetriyas . He simply wiped out a particular clan of the Kshetriyas called 'the Haiyahaya'. This Haiyahaya' dynasty was the bloodline of the King Kartavirarjuna (Sahasrabahu) whom had a conflict with Parshuram's father over the ownership of a celestial cow (Nandini) . This conflict led to a fierce battle where Sahasrabahu came victorious and Jamadagni(Father of Parshuram) was slain.
Now, Parshuram desirous of vengeance swore to wipe out Kartavirarjuna's bloodline and had to circumnavigate the world 21 times to do so.  Another, translation says , The King Kartavirarjuna had 21 sons ruling all over his empire, So Parshuram challenged these 21 sons and killed them thereby earning the repute, He killed Kshetriyas 21 times. But no where has it been mentioned that Kshetriya race got entirely depleted so as to commit the practice of niyoga. There is no need of niyoga , the Kshetriya men that got killed already had left behind offsprings to continue their race.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Answers here must be backed-up with "authoritative sources/references". Kindly visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!